# Split byte array (unknown size) into chunks with leftovers

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, split

I have an array of bytes with an unknown size and I want to convert every four bytes into an integer. The problem is the unknown size as stuff like this will not work:

```
Private Sub(ByVal list() as Byte)
For i = 0 To list.Count - 1 Step 4

Next
```

As if the size is not divideable by 4, it will cause an exception.
So how can I split the array of bytes into chunks of four bytes?

This is my current try but it causes an exception.

```
 Public Function MakeByteChunks(ByVal pByte() As Byte, ByVal pSize As Integer) As List(Of Byte())
    Dim chunkList As New List(Of Byte())
    For i = 0 To pByte.Count - 1
        Dim tmpchunkList(pSize) As Byte
        Array.Copy(pByte, i, tmpchunkList, 0, pSize)
        chunkList.Add(tmpchunkList)
    Next
    Return chunkList
End Function
```

when I'm trying to convert it to integers:

```
 Dim splittedArray = MakeByteChunks(list, 1)
        For i = 0 To splittedArray.Count - 1

Dim Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(splittedArray(i), 0)})              
        Next
```

Comment: That depends on what you are doing within the loop. The code you are showing us right now seems to be perfectly safe.

Comment: As I said I'm trying to convert every four bytes into an integer. That's because I want to read integers out of an byte array. And BitConverter.ToInt32 only takes the offset as parameter.

Comment: Then show how are you doing it

Comment: splittedArray will be the same as the original list as you split your list into chunks of size 1. An Int32 consists of 4 bytes. What do you want to do with the 3 leftover bytes if the list is for instance only 31 bytes long? How are the bytes aligned in your bytearray? LittleEndian vs BigEndian?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the last chunk which can be shorter than 4 just do like this

```
Private Sub(ByVal list() as Byte)
For i = 0 To (list.Count - 3) - 1 Step 4

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

convert byte array to list using ToList  method and add more items using (bytes.Count() + bytes.Count() mod 4).
example:
    var bytes = Enumerable.Repeat (1, 14).Select(b => (Byte)b).ToArray();
            var temp = bytes.ToList();
            temp.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, bytes.Count() %     4).ToArray());

or simply create an integer method (get array length using mentioned array) and use Buffer.BlockCopy to copy items easily:

```
var temp2 = new int[(bytes.Length + bytes.Length % 4) / 4];  
            Buffer.BlockCopy(temp2, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
```